# Creating while-loop with nested loops in it

Tags: java, while-loop

I am trying to create a program that picks a random number, and as the user inputs guesses, the program dictates if it's "too high", "too low", AND keeps a running total. But my while loop only extends over the first nested loop I create, and won't cover anything after that.

I'm coding in Blujay on my mac, but received that same issue on a windows desktop, making me believe its a coding error, not a program one

```
System.out.println("Would you like to play this game? y/n");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
playGame = scan.next().charAt(0);

while (playGame == 'y')
     System.out.println("Please enter a number in 1-100 range");
     userNumber= scan.nextInt();
```

while in Java, the while loop in the code below only cover(or goes purple / gets highlighted) the line with "while (playgame == y)", and the following print statement, but i need the whole program to be under a while loop so the game can repeat as long as the user says "y".

Comment: The above code won't even compile.  Please post the actual code you are running.

Comment: Is `y` defined as variable? should be `'y'`

Comment: if playgame is a char there is a mistake with your comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this valid Java code, you first need semicolons at the end of every statement. That's not the fix for your while loop, and maybe in you actual code you already have that, but I'm just pointing it out.

To make a while loop - or any kind of code block - cover multiple statements in Java, you use curly braces {}. Again, maybe your actual code has this, but the way you're wording your question makes me think you probably don't. So that's:

```
while (condition) {
  statement1;
  statement2;
  ...
}
```

Java does not care about indentation at all, you need the braces and semicolons to make this work.

Comment: i have the semicolons but the curly brackets helped! Thankyou so much!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole code in a `while(true)` statement and exit it when the user chooses to exit the game:

```
    char playGame;
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Would you like to play this game? y/n");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        playGame = scan.next().charAt(0);
        if (playGame != 'y') break;

        System.out.println("Please enter a number in 1-100 range");
        int userNumber = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You entered: " + userNumber); // or something else
    }
```

Comment: thanks so much! i was trying to figure out how to use a break statement and thats great!